# Prevent hyperlink to .bat file, in email to run

Tags: security, microsoft-outlook, batch-file

Using MS Outlook, I'm writing an email in which, I refer to a `.bat` file as an hyperlink to a file *somewhere* on our internal network. However, on-click of the link the `.bat` file actually run the batch file!

Can this behavior be changed? Is there any way, I can pass a file:// link to a `.bat` file, and on click it would **not run** and behave as if it were `.txt` file, where on-click it would simply open the file for edit/reading?

Comment: Does that happen even for the recipient? That would be a **massive** breach of security. I can't imagine any OS allowing that as default behaviour.

Comment: While Outlook has blocked .bat attachments, I don't believe it blocks links by default. I would imagine this is because the OS already handles this security, blocking .bat files from running from untrusted locations by default.

Comment: @lzc I would handle this by sending via email the `File://\\server\share` or `File://C:\folder\path`  with just the path the file exists, and then give instruction to  *Right-Click* and select *Edit* on the `<filename>.bat` to open it up and see the text of the script or edit it. The seems more feasible than trying to manipulate how the `.bat` file is handled as a hyperlink and how the OS execute that assuming Outlook does not block it. This also gives the end-user you send it to the responsibility or doing what needs to be done as per the instruction.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible from within the hyperlink itself.

You would have to setup the link to run Notepad (or another text editor) and then call the bat file, and this capability is not included in standard Hyperlinks.

While you *can* call executables from hyperlinks in Outlook, you cannot pass arguments to those executables. For instance, you can open `C:\Windows\notepad.exe` but you cannot tell `notepad.exe` to open `D:\fu\fu.bat`.

Unless you can confirm 100% that the system is configured to treat `.bat` files as text files (opening them in a text editor rather than attempting to run them), you will not be able to accomplish this without using alternative methods and workarounds.